# How to continuously take backup of log files?

Tags: shell, unix

I have some applications in Linux which create log files, I want to take a backup of these files using unix shell scripting. How can I backup the log files?

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what you are trying to do here exactly. How often? What sort of backup? How much data? Are you looking for log rotation? Short-term backups? Long-term backups? Backups for what purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking fro unix `cron`. Read [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/) for more details. Using cron you can take periodic backups or do some other tasks as well.